# locationInNode: inaccurate after scaling the scene

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I've been struggling with this for a while and would love some help!

I have a tile map in sprite kit, the user can tap any tile and things happen. To get the tile they tapped on, I use something like this:

```objc
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:_mapLayer];
    SKNode *tile = [_mapLayer nodeAtPoint:touchLocation];

    // Do things with the tile...

}
```

However, I also want the user to be able to zoom in and out to get a better view of the map if needed. This is easy enough, I set a pinch recogniser and scale the scene using:

```objc
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    [self runAction:[SKAction scaleBy:recognizer.scale duration:0]];
}
```

Everything works as expected, except that as soon as the scale of the scene is anything other than 1.0, the `locationInNode:` method returns the wrong coordinates, causing `nodeAtPoint:` to return the wrong tile.

For example, if I tap on a tile when the scale is 1.0, everything works. But if I scale the scene down to 0.9 scale and tap the same tile, `locationInNode:` returns the wrong coordinates, and therefore a different tile to the one I tapped on will be selected.

Am I doing something wrong?

**Edit:** I created an image to illustrate my issue in response to Andrey that might help:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpRQs.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What comes to zooming in/out, you're not supposed to scale the scene (like it hints if you try setScale). You're supposed to resize it.

Try this:

After init: `myScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;`

And then while zooming:

```
-(void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer 
{
   float newX = // calculate scaled X
   float newY = // calculate scaled Y
   self.size = CGSizeMake(newX, newY);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocationInView = [touch locationInView:self.scene.view];
    CGPoint touchLocationInScene = [self.scene convertPointFromView:
                                    touchLocationInView];
    CGPoint touchLocationInLayer = [_mapLayer convertPoint:touchLocationInScene
                                                 fromNode:self.scene];
    SKNode *tile = [_mapLayer nodeAtPoint:touchLocationInLayer];

    // Do things with the tile...

}
```

Comment: Thanks your your help mate. Unfortuantelly I get the same issue, here is an image to illustrate: http://i.imgur.com/N1XcyNx.png

Comment: I thought I'd add a bit more info in case it helps: I have a SKScene layer, which is the thing that gets scaled. Inside the scene is only one child node called _worldNode, inside _worldNode is a _mapLayer node which contains the map (and will eventually also hold other layers, but will worry about that when I get past this issue!).